# Subset by two factors variables

Tags: r, aggregate, factors

I'd like to aggregate my dataset considering the interations between two factors (`fac1`, `fac2`) and apply a function for this. For example, consider the dataset given by

```
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(fac1 = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 30, rep = T), 
                   fac2 = sample(c("a", "b"), 30, rep = T), 
                   value = runif(30))
```

For `fac1 == "A"` and `"fac2 == a"` we have five values and I'd like to aggregate by min. Using brutal force I tried this way

```
min(test[test$fac1 == "A" & test$fac2 == "a", ]$value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention `aggregate` and that will work here.

```
aggregate(test$value, test[,1:2], min)
  fac1 fac2          x
1    A    a 0.32535215
2    B    a 0.14330438
3    C    a 0.33239467
4    A    b 0.33907294
5    B    b 0.08424691
6    C    b 0.24548851
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` alternative

```
test %>% group_by(fac1, fac2) %>% summarise(x = min(value))
## A tibble: 6 x 3
## Groups:   fac1 [?]
#  fac1  fac2       x
#  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
#1 A     a     0.325
#2 A     b     0.339
#3 B     a     0.143
#4 B     b     0.0842
#5 C     a     0.332
#6 C     b     0.245
```